# CSS Reset not working

Tags: css, reset, css-reset

I have been working on a little photo slider.  It looks slightly different in Chrome than in FF so I thought a CSS reset would make them both look the same.  I used the Yahoo! YUI CSS reset model but nothing changed.  It looks good in FF but in Chrome the "Resume" button on the right side sticks up too high and a thin gray line at the bottom of the big pictures gets cut off where the main buttons are located.  Here is the URL:

http://www.replayground.com/slider/02.html

You can ignore the stuff below the circles.  Just testing stuff down there.

Here is what I added to my 02.html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/reset/reset-min.css">
```

I'd really like advice on how to get CSS Reset working correctly.  Not how to fix the specific buttons problem you see.  As I add elements to the page I don't want to have to go through this each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A CSS reset is not designed to make all the rest of CSS cross-browser. It is designed to set all of the client default rules on all the different browsers to the same thing so that you are always working from a predictable set of CSS rules. How the browsers interpret those rules is still specific to each one.

In your case, you still need to figure out how to write CSS rules that operate the same in both Chrome and FF - the reset simply levels your starting point a little, it doesn't remove the browser rendering differences.

You may find a cross browser CSS framework (e.g. [blueprintcss.org](http://blueprintcss.org/) or [960.gs](http://960.gs/)) to be more helpful for your current situation. They often use a reset, but also have rules that compensate for the differences in the rendering of the after-reset CSS rules.

Answer (score 1):

jball is very right about the resets. They just allow you to start with a blank page, but you should still write a proper document structure and good CSS to get good and consistent results.

In your case, all elements in your page are loose in the page. This will give you trouble in the end. Some things will shift a few pixels, especially when you don't specify exact height for every item. Fonts are rendered in different heights by each browser. These may be tenths of pixes, but when they get rounded, your website is a little off between browsers.

When you use a little deeper nesting of elements, you can make better use of positioning elements (relative and absolute). If you put in a specific div for the header, and give it a fixed size, you can position each element in there very precisely, which is especially handy for headers and menu's.

I took the liberty of creating a small example, which shows just some basics of positioning. It is not perfect and uses brightly colored borders instead of images for the layout. But it's just for showing the element nesting and absolute and relative positioning, along with a negative margin trick.
http://jsfiddle.net/YwCxQ/3/

Comment: Wow, thank you for creating this example.  I am going to play with it and see what I can find out.

Comment: Actually I figured it out.   I had this line in my CSS file:

margin:1em 0px;

When I changed it to:

margin: 13px 0px;

Then everything worked.  Must be that one browser interpreted the units "em" as slightly different.

Comment: That's very possible. Mixing pixels and points (em=12pt, I think)  is quite hard to do right. Using points, especially for font sizes and line height, is often done to support the visually impared. Setting a larger font size in the browser has effect on text (and other elements) that have a pt or em size. In the lastest browsers, It is easier to zoom the entire page, but they do still have this text-zoom feature. However, many website builders use pixel values, even for font-sizes, to enforce their pages to look exactly the same on all browsers.